# kivy: How to add a callback to a unfocus event on TextIput widgets

Tags: python, kivy, focus

I've got a problem tying callback funtions to the `on_focus` event of a TextInput.

I want it to trigger a validation event when the focus from the input widget is removed. And, in doing so, calling another method (via the `on_validate_text` method)

Here is the code:

```
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.app import App

class MyTextInput(TextInput):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.multiline = False
        self.unfocus_on_touch = True

    def on_focus(self, instance, value):
        if not value:   # DEFOCUSED
            print('Focus is off')

class MainLayout(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols = 2
    #First row
        self.top_label = Label(text = 'No text')
        self.add_widget(self.top_label)
        self.top_input = MyTextInput(on_text_validate=self.change_top_label)

        #Here im trying to trigger the validate event when the on_focus gets called
        self.top_input.bind(on_focus=self.top_input.on_text_validate)

        self.add_widget(self.top_input)
    #Second row
        self.bottom_label = Label(text='Bottom Label')
        self.add_widget(self.bottom_label)
        self.bottom_input = MyTextInput(on_text_validate=self.create_popup)
        self.bottom_input.bind(on_focus=self.bottom_input.on_text_validate)
        self.add_widget(self.bottom_input)

    def change_top_label(self, instance):
        self.top_label.text = instance.text
        instance.text = ''

    def create_popup(self, instance):
        self.my_popup = Popup(title=instance.text, size_hint=(.5, .5))
        self.my_popup.content = Button(text='CLOSE', on_release=self.my_popup.dismiss)
        self.my_popup.open()
        instance.text = ''

if __name__ == '__main__':
    class MainApp(App):
        def build(self):
            return MainLayout()
    MainApp().run()
```

In this case, when de top input gets defocused, I want it to call the `change_top_label` method through the validation event.
In the same way, when the bottom input gets defocused, the `create_popup` method should get called through the validation event.

I need both input to call a callback function when unfocused. But I can not define that function inside the `on_focus` method, because it needs to be different for every instance of MyTextInput.

I've tried binding `on_text_validate` to `on_focus`, and calling `on_text_validate` inside the `on_focus` metyhod, but it does not work.
Clearly there is something I'm missing.

If you could help me out here, It'd be great.

Comment: Could you please elaborate exactly what are you trying to do ?

Comment: I've just eddited the post, so hopefuly it's more clear now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, your code seems already doing what you wanted in the following (after the method `on_text_validate` is being called),

> In this case, when de top input gets defocused, I want it to call the change_top_label method through the validation event...

Secondly,

> I've tried binding on_text_validate to on_focus...

This seems confusing to me. The method `on_text_validate` gets called when you hit 'enter' (and if `multiline` is set to `False`) and that will also unfocus the `TextInput`. Also `on_focus` is kind of a default method that is called whenever the attr. `focus` changes. So and finally if you want just this,

> I need both input to call a callback function when unfocused. But...

You can do that as `TextInput_instance.bind(focus = some_method)`.

Comment: For the first answer:

The code IS doing what it should be doing when I press Enter inside the TextInput. BUT I need it to do the same if I write something, and, without pressing Enter, I quit the focus from that Widget (clicking outside the Widget or focusing the other TextInput)


Sencondly:

I know that that's confusing, because it's wrong. I thought `on_text_validate` could be called whenever I wanted to execute its callback.

Comment: Lastly:

I've added this: `self.top_input.bind(focus=self.change_top_label)` but it passes 3 arguments and that method needs only 2. (I cannot add more argumets, sice I call that method back with the `on_text_validate` method, and it only passes 2.

Comment: EDIT:
I added a intermediate method that gets the focus change, checks if it has been defocused and calls the goal method. Thank very much.